# How to left rotate bits of an Integer

Tags: ruby, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, integer-overflow

I need to left-rotate 32 bits of an Integer by `n` in Ruby. I'm trying with the canonical implementation:

```rb
class Integer
    def rotl32 n
        return (self << n) | (self >> (32 - n))
    end
end
```

Something is going wrong using large numbers: the result overflows 32 bits. I guess it happened because the theoretical unlimited size of an Integer in Ruby.

How can it be done without overflowing?

Comment: No need to put "Ruby :: " in your title; that's what tags are for.

Comment: You can put things in boldface or italics, but do this only when it is really necessary. Emphasis is used to draw extra attention to something. If almost everything demands extra attention, then nothing will get extra attention. "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)" will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby will automatically switch to a different internal representation in order to accommodate larger numbers, so you'll need to cap it with masking:

```
class Integer
  def rotl32(n)
    mask = (1 << (32 - n)) - 1

    ((self & mask) << n) | (self >> (32 - n))
  end
end
```

Where `mask` indicates which bits should be shifted left, the rest effectively trimmed off before shifting.

Ruby will gladly do really ridiculous stuff like `1 << (1 << 16)` which produces a number 19,729 digits long. This is also an Integer.

Note if you need this method more performant you'd want to use a look-up table rather than computing every time, though as always I'd benchmark to make sure that approach is faster.